# Python нужно вывести данные

Tags: python, файлы, случайные-числа, pyautogui

Как сделать так чтоб пайтон напечатал в блокноте рандомные числа с помощью модуля random? Либо чтоб из файла он брал по одной строке и также печатал с помощью pyautogui(я думаю использовать его в двух случиях. Заменены pyautogui  не знаю)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Как создать [mcve]?

Comment: Во-первых, "рандомные числа с помощью random" не "печатаются", а только генерируются.  Во-вторых, какое отношение рандомные числа имеют к чтению информации из файлов? В-третьих, вам что-нибудь про циклы известно? В-четвертых, причем тут pyautogui?

Comment: Passant я говорил сразу про вывод рандомных чисел мне нужно выводить в другое приложения эти числа. Чтение данных из файла это как альтернатива. Мне нужно чтоб не по одной цифре добавлялось мне нужно чтоб мне выводились рандомные числа в другую программу. Pyautogui как я посчитал с помощью него вводятся в программу. И может ли pyautogui читать данные из переменной

Comment: @RAW -  после новой серии ваших вопросов у меня возник один вопрос, но серьезный. А вы вообще Python учили? Ну хоть чуть-чуть? Пару первых страниц любого учебника?

Answer (score 1):

Случайное целое число N, где A ≤ N ≤ B:

```
import random    

N = random.randint(A, B)
print(N)
```

Comment: Мне нужно напечатать в одном приложение результат рандома